# Implementing a conditional for loop

Tags: java

Is there a way to do something like this in Java?

```
for (int i = 0; if (a) { i < x } else { i < y }; i++) { ... }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just create `boolean` variables representing both conditions. Then, depending on the result of the initial condition `a` select the corresponding variable.

Comment: @Zabuza depends whether `a` changes within the loop or not.

Comment: @Aominè Good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; a ? (i<x) : (i<y); i++){}
```

or

```
for(int i = 0; i < (a ? x : y); i++){}
```

It must be asked why you'd want to...

Comment: My example is not exactly the code I have. The for loop needs to change itself midway through.

Comment: @PTwno well, this would work; it's just very difficult to follow.

Comment: @PTwno What do you mean by "change itself"? Like changing direction? 50 up 50 down?

Comment: Better to restructure into two consecutive loops, even if this means pulling out the body into a method.

Comment: @LouisWasserman probably. I considered adding that to my answer when I wrote it, but decided against it because we don't know what is going on in and around the loop, how `a` changes etc. I figured it was better to answer the direct question, and express mild disparagement to hint that it is maybe not the best way to approach it.

Answer (score 3):

A clean approach would be to store the bounds in `int` variables and then select the corresponding variable based on the initial condition:

```
int bound;
if (a) {
    bound = x;
} else {
    bound = y;
}

for (int i = 0; i < bound; i++) {
    ...
}
```

You can use the ternary operator for that kind of assignment like

```
int bound = a ? x : y;
```

Or directly inside the *for loop*:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (a ? x : y); i++) {
    ...
}
```

Be aware that, with the first approach, the condition will only be evaluated once. If it can change inside the loop you will need to update it inside.